# How to quantify amplitude of oscillations in marginally stable systems?

Tags: stability, oscillation, phase-margin

A transfer function pole on the Imaginary axis indicates that the system is marginally stable which in time domain manifests as a sinusoidal motion with constant amplitude at the frequency of the pole. In some lightly damped systems, oscillations or limit cycles with small amplitude might be acceptable.

1. Is amplitude of oscillation for (almost) marginally stable systems is a function of initial condition of the system?
2. How to intuitively quantify amplitude of the oscillations for marginally stable system?
3. Can one use Eigen Vectors to quantify the amplitude of oscillations? If so, how?

PS, I asked this question in Signal Processing Exchange forum but did not get the answer I was looking for.
[1]: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/71587/how-to-quantify-amplitude-of-oscillations-in-marginally-stable-systems

Comment: "Damping ratio" is a number that quantifies it but, whether that's intuitive or not is entirely down to each person. Maybe you are asking the wrong question.

Comment: @Andyaka, damping ratio does quantify amplitude of oscillations in the damped systems. Damping ratio in a marginally stable system is zero.

Comment: Zero is still a number and hence quantifies things.

Comment: @Andyaka, could you please elaborate (with an example if possible) that how the zero damping ratio provides information on amplitude of a marginally stable system?

Comment: In theory, the loop will maintain any amplitude that arises from an input disturbance or an initial condition. In practice the amplitude will be limited by saturation - if a sinusoid grows until the saturation limit is exceeded the effective loop gain is automatically reduced.

Comment: @Alborz plus what chu says. It depends on initial conditions and the driving signal.